# Calling a function of interface C#

Tags: c#, web-services, user-interface, interface

I have a solution that includes two projects: server and GUI. In the GUI project there's a WinForm application, and in the server project there's a Webservice. I know that it's slightly incorrect, but the way it works is as following: my GUI has an instance of the server, and my server has a reference to an interface which the GUI implements. In the GUI constructor it initializes the webservice and sets its reference to itself, so that the server can call the functions of the GUI.

The problem is that there is some problem with calling the GUI functions from the server, and it throws some exception that I cannot find (since that I'm debugging the GUI project). Did I write something wrong? Or is it completely impossible to call functions of an interface?

UPDATE: I think that the problem is that the Webservice that's running and handling the http messages is different from the instance that I create in the GUI somehow. Maybe making the webservice static will help?

code:
server:

```
public class WS : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    ALUMA_GUI gui;

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public void registerUser()
    {
        try
        {
            gui.addUser(tempUser); //This is where it fails
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(e.Message);
        }
    }
 }
```

GUI (implements ALUMA_GUI):

```
public MainForm()
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            server = new WS();
            server.setGUI(this);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
```

Any kind of help would be really appreciated...

Comment: You can debug multiple projects with Visual Studio. Just click on solution and choose `Set startup projects...`.  Web server has to run somewhere - IIS or IISExpress, try to open your web service in browser. Unless disabled you should see its description. If none of those give you clue to your problem add to your question also service mappings from both config files.

Answer (score 2):

Services don't interact with presentation layers in this manner. For the server to be able to call functions in your winforms app, you'd have to serialize the entire app and its functionality and pass it to the server. Even then, you can't pass the state (re: `this`) across the web (stateless). My assumption reading the names of your methods is that you're attempting to use the gui to register a new user, and then have the gui update its current registry of users in local memory.

The proper way to do that would be to have both the gui and the web service operate against the interface of what a user object looks like. Have the gui "register" the user (I'm assuming that means insert into a database), and then return the user object to the gui itself. Then the gui is responsible for making sure the returned user is added properly to any local stored memory.

Comment: That seemed to be the problem, the gui variable in the server wasn't initialized... I didn't get your solution though: the scenario is that the user sends an HTTP request to the webservice and the webservice updates the GUI. You suggest instead that...? Both the GUI and the server operate using the same User class...

Comment: @FitzChivalry: The type, but not the same instance. If you think about it, when you use `new ALUMA_GUI()` on the server, you're actually running a NEW instance of the gui application on the server. This is definitely not an ideal usage of server resources. There is no way for the gui itself to communicate an instance variable to a web service over the web.

Comment: But the server and the GUI don't communicate over the web? I am confused... what do you mean? they have an instance of each other and call functions, they don't send anything on the web...

Comment: @FitzChivalry: They communicate but not in the manner you're attempting to. The server does not have nor should it need an instance of your gui. I honestly think you should read more about web services and how they operate. There's is much more to it than I can deliver in comments, but this understanding of how the communication between server/client (gui) behaves is critical for what you're doing.

Comment: first thing, thank you for your comments. Second - how would you suggest to build it? Is there any way to create a GUI for an ASP web application? How would you implement this?

Comment: @FitzChivalry: There's too much to share in comments. Short version: I would have both the gui and the server merely pass the user object about both of them understanding what an IAlumaUser (an assumed interface name). The gui calls the web service to perform actions, the service performs the actions and returns a meaningful response object back along with the latest copy of the IAlumaUser object. Then based on the response, the gui shifts local memory and displays around to correspond with the server version.

Comment: thanks, but there's one more thing - events that are generated by the server (e.g. user registering with webmethod). Isn't there a smarter way than polling the server with the GUI to find out about these locations?